# Java web JSP can not read CSS file

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm doing a web project using Netbeans. I want to add CSS to my JSP but for some reasons it seems my JSP can not find the CSS.

My Projects file structure is like this in Netbeans

Project Tab

```
myProject
   -Web Pages
      -WEB-INF
      -view
          -css
             -logincss.css
          -jsp
             -login
                -login.jsp
   -Source Packages
   -etc.. .
```

in my JSP I link css like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/css/logincss.css">
```

I think i'm linking it right? If i'm doing it wrong please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this, 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/logincss.css">

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: Can you check the browser console for any errors?

Comment: Yea it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of logincss.css 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: What is the URL of the login.jsp page (i.e. browser's address line) and what is the URL in the `href` attribute?

Comment: Hi its "http://localhost:8080/CMSv1/jsp/login/login.jsp" when I run it in netbeans. My href "href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/css/logincss.css"

Comment: no sorry its "http://localhost:8080/CMSv1/view/jsp/login/login.jsp"

Comment: Here me out, I just created a simple maven web project, create jsp and css, link the css to the jsp and run it, it worked! now I copy those jsp and css to my real project and run it, does not work. So I think the problem may be in my main project. But I have no idea where or what.